# JSON data list dynamic

Tags: android, json

I am working in Android just for a heads up. I was able to retrieve JSON data but now I have come to the point where there are multiples. Example:

```
"workers":[
                {
                    "id":3357,
                    "username":"Unreliable.worker",
                    "password":"x",
                    "monitor":0,
                    "count_all":41,
                    "count_all_archive":0,
                    "hashrate":477,
                    "difficulty":106.56
                },
                {
                    "id":4061,
                    "username":"Unreliable.worker2",
                    "password":"x",
                    "monitor":0,
                    "count_all":0,
                    "count_all_archive":null,
                    "hashrate":0,
                    "difficulty":0
                }
```

would I have to do a for loop or is there another way to do it?

This is the code that I am using now to get them:

```
JSONObject workersJSONObject = personalJSONObject.getJSONObject("workers");
```

but I don't know how I would get for each and separate them. I'll get them by using:

```
id= workersJSONObject.getDouble("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` in JSON refers to a `JSON array`. You could use something like:

```
JSONArray workersJSONArray = personalJSONObject.getJSONArray("workers");
```

Then loop through each item as (basically get each `object` inside `array`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < workersJSONArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject workersJSONObject = workersJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // parse object just like before 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On JSON, {} defines an object, [] defines an array instead. if you want details. see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

sample:

```
JSONArray workersJSOnArray = new JSONArray(stringData);
   or 
JSONArray workersJSOnArray = personalJSONObject.getJSONArray("workers");


/* THen you can loop from each data you want */
int len = workersJSOnArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   JSONObject item = workersJSOnArray.optJSONObject(i);

   int id = item.getInt ("id");
   .....
}
```